# Make overflow hidden when shrinking div

Tags: css, image, overflow

I have a div with an image in it, and the image is too large for the div. I have solved the overflow problem with the obvious CSS overflow:hidden trick.

But, the problem is that when the div's parent resizes (shrinks), the div holding the image won't shrink because of the image in it.

Is there a way to have a resizable div with an image in it (almost like a background image) that overflows?

MY DIV STRUCTURE:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="image_holder">
        <!-- this image will inevitably be larger than its parent div -->
        <img src="too_big_for_div.jpg" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

MY CSS:

```
#parent { width:100%;}
#image_holder { width:100%; overflow:hidden;}
```

The #image_holder div will not resize to a smaller dimension now. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the inner div will resize, as it has a width of 100%, but you won't notice it. You probably want to resize the image, too?

Comment: Marcel, yes, you would think....but the inner div isn't resizing. I don't know what is going on. And -- I'd have to resize the image on the fly (when someone resizes their window after the page is loaded, and therefore the divs must resize)

Comment: I think your question is wrong; I just tested your code (with a 1600x1200 image) and the inner div *does* resize along with the outer one. But you want the *image* to resize. Do you want it to fit in the browser's viewport?

Comment: marcel...hmm...its just not working for me the same way it is for you...i dont want the image to resize. jsut the div around it

Comment: Even Ioannis below has the same result; which browser do you use? And as he states, there must be something else wrong. Can you post more of you source code? And please remember to use [@first-name](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to reply to someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 've tested your code and it does resize the inner div. To actually observe it, try setting the border property of the image_holder, and also set the parent 's percentage width to a lower value like so:

```
#image_holder { width:100%; overflow:hidden; border: 1px solid red;}
#parent { width:70%;}
```

If you resize the browser window and can observe the rightmost border, it means your DIV resizes normally. Perhaps there's something else wrong.

If you could provide more info, I'd be glad to help...

P.S.: Tested in IE8, FF 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

First, try to set the parent both width/height with pixels, not pct.

Also, won't a overflow hidden on parent would have the desired effect?

Comment: Mike, yeah the parent's overflow works, but in this specific case, i need the parent div to be resizeable. it needs to be a percentage that expands or contracts with the browser's width...as someone resizes on the fly

Comment: If you don't find your answer and you're in a hurry, you can put your image in the background of the inner DIV

Answer (score 0):

```
#parent{width:100%;overflow:hidden;}
#image_holder{width:inherit;}
```

Comment: Mike, that works if the div is larger than the image, but once the parent div's width is smaller than the image, the inner div hits the image's edge and wont get any smaller, meaning the parent won't either

Comment: make your parent div equivalent to an em measurement for fluid resizing.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the image a background image of `image-holder` it should resize properly regardless of widths of the corresponding divs (assuming overflow and attachment are properly configured)